# C# thread started in another class

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I have one main form class and another class. In the second class, I have a thread loop:

```
    public void StartListening()
    {
        listening = true;
        listener = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoListening));
        listener.Start();
    }


    // Listening for udp datagrams thread loop
    /*=====================================================*/
    private void DoListening()
    {
        while (listening)
        {
            IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            byte[] content = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteIPEndPoint);

            if (content.Length > 0)
            {
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(content);
                delegMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }

    // Stop listening for udp datagrams
    /*=====================================================*/
    public void StopListening()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            listening = false;
        }
    }
```

In main form class, I start this listening in class constructor

```
       udp.StartListening();
```

And than, in this main form class, I have key hook event, too. In this event, I wan to stop thread running in the second class.

```
    private void hook_KeyPressed(int key)
    {
        if (key == (int)Keys.LMenu)
            altPressed = true;
        if (key == (int)Keys.F4 && altPressed == true)
        udp.StopListening();
    }
```

Unfortunetely, the thread is still running.
Do you have some ideas about this??

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you debugged your `while(listening)` loop *after* you call `StopListening` to check if the state has in fact changed?

Comment: Did you debugged and checked whether `StopListening` executed?

Comment: Yes I tried, it's a problem that "listening" is still true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your thread is blocking at the `byte[] content = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteIPEndPoint);` line.  The Receive method blocks until something is received.

You should use the asynchronous version ([BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive.aspx)) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try have a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

Also, another flaw in your code - you check for the stopping condition without any synchronization. Here:

```
   private void DoListening()
   {
    while (listening){ //this condition could stuck forever in 'false'
   }
```

Actually, without a memory barrier, there is no guarantee, that a thread, that is running `DoListening` will ever see the change to `listening` var from other thread. You should at least use locking here (which provides memory barrier)

Comment: A valid point, but I prefer not to mess with volatile, until absolutely necessary: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility

Comment: You're right. I'm not yet proficient in threads synchronization, unfortunetely...

Comment: @undefined wow. Well if Joe Duffy and Joseph Albahari say to watch out that's definitively a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

As @igelineau pointed out - your code is blocking on the receive call.  If you don;t want to go down the async route (which I'd recommend) just send something to the udp port in your stop listening method.